# Set keyframes and change origin problem

Tags: animation, keyframes, origin

I want to build this simple animation without switching to different collections.

https://youtu.be/OXWZ6dNqdLc

From frame 1 - 30 change origin, rotate then set keyframe locrot 
go to frame 60 change origin rotate then set keyframe locrot 
oooh ... frame 1-30 is ruined ... ahhh
Try it and this drives you mad. 
There is a better way to do this ?

Comment: why don't you do that with bones?

Comment: You can create a hierarchy with parenting the objects to each other, you don't have to use collections.

Comment: Meanwhile I tried with empties but get weird spin. With bones it worked well. Hierarchy of parented objects ? I dont know how to do.

Comment: I tried it with parented objects in hierarchy and yes it worked too. Thx very much !